# Is there a tool to generate XML picklers in Haskell from an XSD?

Tags: haskell, xsd, code-generation

I'd like to generate [XML picklers](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT/Conversion_of_Haskell_data_from/to_XML#The_idea%3a_XML_pickler) for an [XSD file](http://www.energysoft.org/Title24XML.xsd). It seems like a useful tool that might already exist. Does it?

Comment: Not an answer, but at Silk we wrote regular-xmlpickler, which generates XML picklers from the Haskell data types. This gives you a schema as well. I'm not sure if it's useful to you, since it goes in the other direction.

Comment: Hi Eric, I saw posts about that and I was intrigued. I may use it as it would save me from coding the picklers by hand, but I was hoping to find a full solution.

Answer (score 2):

`HaXml` does have a tool for generating Haskell data types from DTDs and a tool for generating Haskell data types from XSDs: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml

The executables are named XsdToHaskell and DtdToHaskell.

If you're on Windows and you have PATH modified by Haskell Platform, you'll need to call it like this: `xsdtohaskell < path_to.xsd > path_to.hs`

The generated files are a decent starting point.

Comment: FWIW, I was trying a few different ways to install it, ultimately went with `cabal new-install HaXML`, and found binaries in `~/.cabal/bin`