# How to validate XML (via an XSD file) in Haskell?

Tags: xml, validation, haskell, xsd, hxt

I am already using HXT for transforming XML. Now I want to validate the input and output against a XSD-file.

HXT only seem to include [RELAXNG](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-relaxng-9.1.4) and [DTD validators](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.3.1.1/doc/html/Text-XML-HXT-DTDValidation-Validation.html).

I don't really care to use something else for just validating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to generate XML picklers in Haskell from an XSD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022758/is-there-a-tool-to-generate-xml-picklers-in-haskell-from-an-xsd)

Comment: @PaulSweatte, how exactly should this be a duplicate? The question you are referencing is about generating algebraic data types and serializers/deserializers from XSDs. Doing so may also involve validation - but it is a completely different topic.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think is HaXml and some elbow grease: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.25.3

In particular, you have tools to parse XSD and to validate DTD. However I don't there's an "out of the box" way to validate XSD -- it could be possible to smash the info you want into their DTD format, or you could replicate their validation logic against the parsed XSD.

At least that's a start...